# Existence and uniqueness of solution to linear pde with "mixed Cauchy" boundary condition.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, cauchy-problem

Suppose $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a bounded domain, suppose $\partial\Omega=\Gamma_1\cup\Gamma_2$ where $\Gamma_i$ are smooth curves, now consider the following elliptic pde:
$$\begin{cases}Lu=f,\  &\Omega\\
u=g,\ & \Gamma_1\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=h,\ & \Gamma_2
\end{cases}$$
where $(f,g,h)$ are enough regular. Do we have any existence and uniqueness result of this type of problem? If there is, how about the regularity of the solution? I don't find any discussions in Gilbarg and Trudinger's book. Would anyone point me some references?

Comment: You need the assumption that $\Gamma_1$ has positive length, but then it should work. I do not recall where I read this though.

Comment: @supinf Yes, I am asking some results by assuming certain properties as good as you want.